# can a planet be in the habitable zone of a blue star be the best option or a star that gives off more blue light

Tags: planets, flora, stars, colors

My planet originally was in a system with a blue star, but I think they are unstable and so it's not the best. So what type of stars give off more blue light in order for plants to be yellow or blue. And what is the habitable zone of a star that gives off more blue light, and can there be other options with a similar effect?

Answer (score 1):

**The color of plants does not depend on the color of the sun.**

[image: pigments]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EnglrmTR6GA

Here are real photosynthetic pigments.  They are a variety of colors and capture energy from a variety of wavelengths.  Our star kicks out lots of different wavelengths.  These pigments capture the energy from certain wavelengths not because those wavelengths are more energetic, but because chance produced molecules that were able to do that.

Also note that the color of the pigment is not necessarily closely related to the optimal wavelength it absorbs.  And also: the color of a plant might have nothing to do with its photosynthetic pigments.  I have a Natal plum whose leaves turn red in direct sun.  It is a pigment produced to protect from sunlight, not a photosynthetic pigment.

It is fun to have alien stars and fun to invent colorful alien plants.  Do not feel constrained by your star as regards coloring your plants!

Comment: got it thank you for the informationg

Comment: yeah i meant wavelengths not the light in general

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of habitable planets discussed by scientists.

One)

Most scientific disussion are about planets habitable for liquid water using lifeforms in general.

Suppose that a supernatural being teleported you to a randomingly selected point in the planet Earth's biosphere where lifeforms live.  You would almost certainly die, since Earth's biosphere extends for kilometers above and below the surface.  You maight appear kilometers high in the sky amoung birds and floating micro organisms and plummet to your death.  You might appear deep under the sea or inside solid rock.

If you are teleported to a randomly selected place on the surface of the Earth, you will have about a 70 percent chance of drowning in the ocean out of sight of the nearest land.  If you are teleported to a randomly spot on the land area of Earth without knowing where, you won't be able to prepare with the right clothing and other survival gear and might die within days or hours.

Earth is full of lifeforms that can survive in places deadly for humans.  And some planets might be totally uninhabitable for any lifeforms on Earth but still be habitable for liquid water using lifeforms which evolved there.  Planets habitable for humans and beings with similar requirementsin particular are a minority of all planets habitable for liquid water using life in general.

Two)

Planets habitable for humans, and for other life forms with the same environmental requirements.

And as far as I know the main scientific discussion of planets habitable for humans is *Habitable Planets for Man*, Stephen H. Dole, 1964.

https://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/commercial_books/2007/RAND_CB179-1.pdf

And science fiction writers should read what Dole says on pages 67 to 75 about the types of stars which can have planets habitable for humans (and life forms with similar requirements).

And also:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetary_habitability#Spectral_class

And:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habitability_of_red_dwarf_systems

And:

[https://www.space.com/25716-alien-life-hotter-stars.html#:~:text=(Earth%20and%20the%20Sun%20are,of%20approximately%2010%20billion%20years.)](https://www.space.com/25716-alien-life-hotter-stars.html#:%7E:text=(Earth%20and%20the%20Sun%20are,of%20approximately%2010%20billion%20years.))

Any star that can stay of the main sequence for 500 millior or a billion years might possibly have planets which develop simple life forms before the star enters the giant stage of its development.

But if a writer wants a planet with multi celled life forms big enough to see without a microsope, and especially if they want a planet with an oxygen rich atmosphere that humans, large land animals, or intelligent aliens can breathe, they should stay within the limitations of spectral type stars selected by Dole.

Comment: that wasent the awnser is was expecting but a welcomed one

Answer (score -3):

Try the star Canopus its color is mostly blue and has some white not unstable and shows strong signs of convection in its atmosphere. [Here](https://www.google.com/search?q=canopus&rlz=1CATAVM_enUS914&ei=zBdwYd_UG9Wp0PEP1JeF8AU&ved=0ahUKEwjf6o25itnzAhXVFDQIHdRLAV4Q4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=canopus&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQgAEJECMgUIABCRAjIICAAQgAQQsQMyCwgAELEDEIMBEJECMgUIABCRAjIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEOgcIABBHELADOgQIIRAKOgcIIRAKEKABOgYIABAWEB46BQghEKsCOggILhCABBCTAjoLCC4QgAQQxwEQrwE6CwguEIAEEMcBENEDOgcIABCABBAKOgUILhCABEoECEEYAFD_8ANYk4YEYNKIBGgBcAJ4AoABigSIAa8VkgEMMC4xMy4wLjEuMC4xmAEAoAEByAEIwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz&safe=active&ssui=on) is some more information about Canopus.

Comment: that seems intresting

Comment: We are not after link only answers. Please enrich the answer with the relevant part of that link, else it might get deleted

Comment: This isn't even a link to an answer, it is a link to a google search for "canopus".